# Symfony2 app from scratch

Tags: php, symfony, social-networking

I got a project to build using Symfony2 Framework. The project is like a social networking site like facebook, google circle, linkedIn, etc.

The desired features are:

• Rapid development of initial prototype social networking website with minimal coding required (in a week or two, say)

• Control to eventually customize few key components of the website (code about 5% of functionality from scratch)

• Support for: profile (picture, self description, etc.), forum, messaging, friending

I have already installed and configured Symfony 2 on the server. I want to know where should I start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by reading **ALL** the available **documentation** so you're familiar with features offered by the framework: http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html

I mean ALL the documentation (The book, the cookbooks, the components, everything). **Seriously.**

Read [A year with Symfony](https://leanpub.com/a-year-with-symfony) to learn even more about Symfony.

Read few Symfony related blogs, for example:

- http://richardmiller.co.uk/
- http://fabien.potencier.org/
- http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/
- http://www.whitewashing.de/

Than read some more.

Browse through [available bundles](http://knpbundles.com/) to see what you could quickly use in your prototype.

Also, if there's no appropriate bundle solving your problem, search on https://packagist.org/ - might be there's a PHP library you could use and integrate it with Symfony by creating a bundle (and potentially open sourcing it).

Answer (score 1):

Symfony2 is a framework, which means that it provides good practices, coding standards and design patterns, plus an amazing set of bundles that provide a lot of functionalities.
But i think if you never touched it, develop a social network application, even as proof of concept, in only one or two weeks will be difficult. 
If you want to discover Symfony2, i think you should take your time, read a lot and try things step by step.

Comment: Thanks heaps. Sure will do